# Why is cummin/cummax not defined for Date objects and is there any danger in interim numeric conversion?

Tags: r, date

`cummin`/`cummax` cannot be used for Date object. This triggers `Error in Math.Date(x): cummax not defined for "Date" objects`.

I was wondering what's the reasoning behind this since I would think it is entirely possible to determine a cumulative minimum/maximum for dates. Especially since min/max **are** defined for Date objects, this restriction seems samewhat arbitrary.

The solutions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56242301/8107362) are either using `zoo::rollapplyr()` or an interim conversion.

### Questions

1. Whats the reasoning of `cummin`/`cummax` are not defined for dates?
2. Are there any **risks** in the interim conversion? I can think of issues about **precision** or **origin** but I am lacking the creativity in which casesthere really would be an issue.

### Code

#### Example Data

```
x <- as.Date(c("2022-01-01", "2023-01-01", "1900-01-01", "2024-01-01"),
             origin = "1970-01-01")
```

#### Direct Usage

```
# not working
cummax(x)
#> Error in Math.Date(x): cummax not defined for "Date" objects
cummin(x)
#> Error in Math.Date(x): cummin not defined for "Date" objects
```

#### Using {zoo}s `rollapplyr()`

```
zoo::rollapplyr(x, FUN = min, width = seq_along(x))
#> [1] "2022-01-01" "2022-01-01" "1900-01-01" "1900-01-01"
zoo::rollapplyr(x, FUN = max, width = seq_along(x))
#> [1] "2022-01-01" "2023-01-01" "2023-01-01" "2024-01-01"
```

#### Interim Conversion

```
# convert to numeric works
x_num <- as.numeric(x)
cummax(x_num)
#> [1] 18993 19358 19358 19723
cummin(x_num)
#> [1]  18993  18993 -25567 -25567

# converting back into dates gives the correct result
as.Date(cummax(x_num), origin = "1970-01-01")
#> [1] "2022-01-01" "2023-01-01" "2023-01-01" "2024-01-01"
as.Date(cummin(x_num), origin = "1970-01-01")
#> [1] "2022-01-01" "2022-01-01" "1900-01-01" "1900-01-01"
```

##### Functionized

```
cummax_date <- function(x) {
  stopifnot("x must be a Date object" = inherits(x, "Date"))
  x_num <- as.numeric(x)
  x_cummax <- cummax(x_num)
  attr(x_cummax, which = "class") <- class(x)
  return(x_cummax)
}
cummax_date(x)
#> [1] "2022-01-01" "2023-01-01" "2023-01-01" "2024-01-01"
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a nice example to play with object orientation in R.  When you do

```
> x <- as.Date(c("2022-01-01", "2023-01-01", "1900-01-01", "2024-01-01")) 
> x
[1] "2022-01-01" "2023-01-01" "1900-01-01" "2024-01-01"
> 
> cummin(x)
Error in Math.Date(x) : cummin not defined for "Date" objects
>
```

it hints what the issue is: no method defined. Looking at *e.g.* `help(round.Date)` gives an idea because the documentation mentions these as
S4 methods.  We can basically copy the implementation as you already demonstrated that `cummin()` and `cummax()` work just fine with the underlying object (with are basic numeric vectors denoting fractional days since the epoch).

So with

```
> cummax.Date <- function(x, ...) .Date(NextMethod(), oldClass(x))
> cummin.Date <- function(x, ...) .Date(NextMethod(), oldClass(x))
```

we are now done:

```
> x <- as.Date(c("2022-01-01", "2023-01-01", "1900-01-01", "2024-01-01")) 
> cummin(x)
[1] "2022-01-01" "2022-01-01" "1900-01-01" "1900-01-01"
> cummax(x)
[1] "2022-01-01" "2023-01-01" "2023-01-01" "2024-01-01"
>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! May I ask some follow up questions?: (1) why do you  use `oldClass`  instead of `class`? (2) Why `.Date` instead of `class<-` - since we set the class explicitly it seems potentially misleading to use .Date, even though the function is only called on date objects.  In short: Is this equivalent?:  `'class<-'(NextMethod(), class(x))` (2b) and out of curiosity: why does `class(NextMethod()) <- oldClass(x)`  not work?

Comment: (3) how does `NextMethod()` work in this instance? ` x` only has one class, so why is then `x` eventually processed as double (its type)? Does `NextMethod` strip  x` from the (first) class? I wanted to check it but `debugonce(cummin)` does not trigger the debugger to check `x` within `cummin`

Comment: Additionally:  even though you provided a nice way of dealing with this issue, it feels like it does not directly answer my questions: why is it undefined for dates and if it bears any risks to use cummin/cummax on dates?

Comment: Look at how the `round()` method is implemented by _e.g._ typing `round.Date<ENTER>` at the R prompt.  As you will see, we can borrow _the exact same scheme_ for `cummin` and `cummax`.  And if it is 'good enough for base R' in one case ...

Answer (score 1):

The `tidyverse/purrr` solution:

```
aux <- as.Date(
  c("2022-01-01", "2023-01-01", "1900-01-01", "2024-01-01"),
  origin = "1970-01-01")

purrr::accumulate(aux, max)

[1] "2022-01-01" "2023-01-01" "2023-01-01" "2024-01-01"
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  However, I am not looking for another way to solve this but rather ensure my way is not prone to errors.